# RegEx to match only multiples of 5 from 5 up to 150?

Tags: javascript, regex

I don't know how to handle the conditions I have listed below.

I can do one scenario at a time, but not sure how to encompass all restrictions on one field:

- Allows 1, 2 or 3 total digits in the field
- If user enters only 1 digit
  It can only be a `5`
- If user enters 2 digits
  ‐ First digit can be `1-9`
  ‐ Second digit can only be `0` or `5`
- If user enters 3 digits
  ‐ First digit can only be a `1`
  ‐ Second digit can be `0-5`
    • If second digit is `0-4`, third digit can only be `0` or `5`
    • If second digit is a `5`, third digit can only be `0`

Furthermore, if possible:
Each scenario can be followed by the characters `.00` or not
(the `.00` should be optional for entry)

Comment: Welcome, @B-Nice. Please show what you have tried. It would be helpful if you provided a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: This is very easy if you know about [alternation](http://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html), [character classes](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) and [(non-capturing) groups](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html).

Comment: @B-Nice, you may be able to turn those down votes upside down if you edit your question to show the RegEx you started with. Also, did my answer help you?

Comment: After the edits, I really don't think this question can be considered too broad. I would like to see it reopened.

Answer (score 1):

### Use the alternation `|` token and…

You can use the alternation token `|` in conjunction with beginning `^` and end `$` of line tokens to capture 1-, 2-, or 3-digit matches.

You can then optionally match the `.00` string with a non-capturing group `(?:)` and the optional `?` token to match zero or one of that group.

**Update:**

<s>[`/^5(?:\.00)?$|^[1-9][05](?:\.00)?$|^1[0-4][05](?:\.00)?$|^150(?:\.00)?$/gm`](http://regexr.com/3cu9u)</s>

Commenter [bobble bubble](/questions/35775740/js-regex-to-match-only-multiples-of-5-up-to-150/35776143#comment59229095_35776143) provided this more concise version.

[`/^(?:5|[1-9][05]|1[0-4][05]|150)(?:\.00)?$/gm`](https://regex101.com/r/pW0iN8/2)

[image]

Source: [Regexper.com](http://regexper.com/#%2F%5E(%3F%3A5%7C%5B1-9%5D%5B05%5D%7C1%5B0-4%5D%5B05%5D%7C150)(%3F%3A%5C.00)%3F%24%2Fgm)

Comment: I think you could shorten it a bit. Came up with [`^(?:5|[1-9][05]|1[0-4][05]|150)(?:\.00)?$`](https://regex101.com/r/pW0iN8/2) which is very similar to yours. @B-Nice I find your question indeed shows effort. You probably earned the downvotes because of not providing your own regex attempt (personally I don't find your question bad).

Comment: Absolutely, @bobblebubble. I didn't go that extra mile, but I'm glad you shared this.